# What is the location of database if doing Code First using SqlServer CE 4.0?

Tags: c#, database, winforms, entity-framework, entity-framework-4

I am learning Code First development with a console application.  In many of the examples, including Scott Gu's post, they suggest using Sql Server CE 4.0 and set it up so that the code creates the database automagically.

I am doing a console app and would like to examine the database with a management tool, such as management studio or linqpad.  What is the location of the sdf file that is created?

I created an App.Config and placed the following in it:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<configuration>
  <connectionStrings>
    <add
      name="NerdDinners"
      providerName="System.Data.SqlServerCe.4.0"
      connectionString="Data Source =|DataDirectory|NerdDinners.sdf"/>
  </connectionStrings>
</configuration>
```

However, NerdDinner is not created, and instead a database in SQLExpress is created.  I seem to have confused some things here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It depends upon the connection string you have set in app.config file. In most cases (`DataDirectory`) database file will be created at `Debug\bin` folder (winform app).

Sample app: (Add the ref of `System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.dll` and `EntityFramework.dll`)

```
public class Employee
{
    [Key]
    public int EmpNo { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
public class Test : System.Data.Entity.DbContext
{
    public System.Data.Entity.DbSet<Employee> Emps { get; set; }
}
```

app.config (The name of connection string must match the name of `Context` class)

```
<configuration>
<connectionStrings>
  <add  name="Test"
          connectionString="Data source=|DataDirectory|Test.sdf" 
          providerName="System.Data.SqlServerCe.4.0"
        />
</connectionStrings>
</configuration>
```

Add a record,

```
Test db = new Test();

db.Emps.Add(new Employee() { EmpNo = 1, Name = "Mr.X" });
db.SaveChanges();
```

Comment: would it be possible for you to supply an example connection string?  I'm not sure that I've specified mine correctly

Comment: @MedicineMan - The name of connection string must match the name of Context class.